# Using memcached on only part of PHP website

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I have a website I am building using PHP and mysql and want to integrate memcached into the site.

However I was only thinking about adding it to certain pieces (such as queries that look for the amount of products and prices in the store, or the users information).

Would this be wise or would it be better to add memcached to all sql queries?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no idea why someone voted down, good question, not many people are clear with memcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to only cache important parts of my application that were used the most after looking around [here for important information](http://papermashup.com/using-memcache-with-php/) and [here for sessions](http://orig.keboola.com/blog/php-sessions-with-memcached)